# Data Binding between Polymer Templatizer instance and host

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer

I am trying to use the Polymer templatizer to create a single instance of a template, append it into a div and get data binding to work between the host and this instance but am having difficulty getting this to work.

The most simple example I have tried:

HTML

```
<dom-module id="test-app">
  <paper-input label="host" value="{{test}}"></paper-input>
  <template id="template">
    <paper-input label="instance" value="{{test}}"></paper-input>
  </template>
  <div id="placehere"></div>
</dom-module>
```

JS

```
Polymer({
  is: "test-app",
  behaviors: [Polymer.Templatizer],
  properties: {
    test: {
      type: String,
      value: 'hello',
      notify: true,
    },
  },

  ready: function() { 
    this.templatize(this.$.template);
    var clone = this.stamp({test: this.test}); 
    Polymer.dom(this.$.placehere).appendChild(clone.root);
  },
});
```

The idea above is to create the instance of the template, place it into "placehere" and have the two input text boxes keep in sync.

When the page loads, the instance is created successfully and the value in both textboxes is "hello" but changing either input box does nothing.

The documentation on the polymer page seems a bit lightweight:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Templatizer
but it mentions the use of _forwardParentProp and _forwardParentPath. How exactly am I supposed to implement them in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already figured out, you need to implement some of the Templatizer's methods. Particularly the `_forwardParentProp` and `_forwardParentPath` methods.

But before I begin, I must also point out one additional error in your custom elements definition. In your `dom-module` element, you have the element's contents defined without the template. It is essential to wrap everything within a `template` element. The fixed version of your custom element would be like this:

```
<dom-module id="test-app">
  <template>
    <paper-input label="host" value="{{test}}"></paper-input>
    <template id="template">
      <paper-input label="instance" value="{{test}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
    <div id="placehere"></div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

As for the implementation of the Templatizer methods, you first need to store the stamped instance. After that, both methods that need implementations are more or less simple one-liners.

Here is the full JavaScript part of the custom element:

```
Polymer({
  is: "test-app",
  behaviors: [Polymer.Templatizer],
  properties: {
    test: {
      type: String,
      value: 'hello',
      notify: true,
    },
  },

  ready: function() { 
    this.templatize(this.$.template);
    var clone = this.stamp({test: this.test});
    this.stamped = clone.root.querySelector('*'); // This line is new
    Polymer.dom(this.$.placehere).appendChild(clone.root);
  },

  // This method is new
  _forwardParentProp: function(prop, value) {
    if (this.stamped) {
        this.stamped._templateInstance[prop] = value;
    }
  },

  // This method is new
  _forwardParentPath: function(path, value) {
    if (this.stamped) {
        this.stamped._templateInstance.notifyPath(path, value, true);
    }
  },
});
```

Here is a working JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/saketemehi/1/edit?html,js,output